Is it possible to transform an XSLT stylesheet with an XSLT stylesheet?
I have a two-step build process. In the first step I want to read configuration from a small XML file conforming to a well-defined XSD schema into an XSLT stylesheet which then outputs another intermediate XSLT stylesheet containing a list of <xsl:param /> elements with the data from the configuration XML. In the second step I want to run a transform on my main XML document with a stylesheet that references the output of the first step with <xsl:include>.
I am stuck at the first step - because the XSLT transformer understands the <xsl:...> schema, it won't blindly output elements in that schema as it would elements in literally every other schema.
I am using XSLT 1.0 because I am in .NET land.
I realise can (and probably will have to) write a console app to read the config XML and set the global params for the transform, but I was hoping to achieve the whole thing with XSLT...
I've tried fiddling with the namespaces in the <xsl:stylesheet> element but I can't figure out a way to get it to emit a valid XSLT stylesheet.

Yes, it IS possible to transform a XSLT stylesheet (just like any other XML document) with another XSLT stylesheet. To separate between XSL instructions and XSL output elements you need to use a namespace alias. Read about it in the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#literal-result-element.

I accept that this is a duplicate question, however I think it still adds some value as the referenced question appears superficially to be PHP specific and my question text might help others who also missed the referenced question.

Yes, you can use XSLT to generate XSLT, use <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix = prefix | "#default" result-prefix = prefix | "#default" />, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Creating-Elements-and-Attributes.
As for being restricted to XSLT 1.0, Saxon HE exists for .NET framework from Saxonica https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE and I have repackaged that for .NET 6 or 8 with https://www.nuget.org/packages/SaxonHE10Net31Xslt. But that is not relevant to namespace aliasing.

Re Saxon HE - my build environment (Azure DevOps) has pwsh on the hosted build server, which in turn has native .NET, but I do not want to faff with references to external modules in this context.
